# force absolute elements position, managed by jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui

Here are several "areas" managed by jquery-ui.

```
<body class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <div id="divWin1" class="ui-widget-content block" style="display: inline-block; margin: 4px; min-width: 800px; min-height: 600px; overflow: none;">
            <label class="clsWindowCaption">WIN 1</label>
        </div>
        <div id="divWin2" class="ui-widget-content block" style="display: inline-block; margin: 4px; min-width: 800px; min-height: 200px; overflow: none;">
            <label class="clsWindowCaption">WIN 2</label>
        ...
```

How to force their absolute positions ?
Following code does not works correctly.

```
$("#divWin1")[0].style["top"] = "10px"
$("#divWin1")[0].style["left"] = "10px"
            
$("#divWin2")[0].style["top"] = "100px"
$("#divWin2")[0].style["left"] = "100px"
```

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].